# Update table based on another table info

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
bb_product (columns > id_seller and hide_from_listings)

instagram_users (columns > user_id and username)
```

Both `user_id` and `id_seller` are the same number.

I need to update `hide_from_listings` to "1", if the username is equal to a specific value.

**Example:**

```
username = chocolate

user_id = 123

id_seller = 123

set hide_from_listings for username = chocolate > 1
```

This is what i've got so far:

```
Update bb_product 
inner join instagram_users on (user_id.instagram_users = id_seller.bb_product)
set hide_from_listings = 1 where username.instagram_users = "chocolate"
```

Comment: And what's the error or unexpected behaviour you are experiencing?

Comment: Can you add what your curent query does or what is the error etc..

Answer (score 0):

1. Select id of users matching criteria into php array
2. update the table using `where userid in( $implodedIds)` where `$implodedIds = implode($userids)`